# HTAccess rewrite PHP GET in one directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one particular directory where I want to mask the URL. It looks like this right now:

```
https://www.example.com/users/invoice/?order=0000000
```

I want it to look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/users/invoice/0000000
```

---

I tried adding this line to my root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/invoice/(.*)$   users/invoice/?order=$1 [L]
```

but this causes a 500 error when I try to access any URL under `/users/invoice/`.

What am I doing wrong? And is there a way to write a rule directly into an .htaccess file in `/users/invoice/`?

Comment: what about creating your .htacess file under invoice instead of the root directory with a simpler rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/invoice/(.+)$ users/invoice/?order=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Without above `RewriteCond` your rule will loop infinitely and cause 500 internal error eventually.

Comment: Why will it loop infinitely?

Comment: Because `users/invoice/.*` will also match `users/invoice/index.php`

Comment: Where does the `index.php` come from?

Comment: My only problem with this is that if I go to `https://www.example.com/users/invoice/asdf`, it will change the URL to `https://www.example.com/users/invoice/?order=asdf`. I want to mask the URL so that the end user doesn't see all of the GET variables.

Comment: @David: Check updated answer, it shouldn't change the URL now. @showdev `index.php` or any other `index.*` is default handler in that directory.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize that was a directory. In the OP's code, it says `invoice?order=$1`.

Comment: Alright great. That works. Thanks so much. I didn't know about Rewrite Conditions being so important.

Comment: @David Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying, guys.